# How can I find nested objects in a document?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to figure out how I can query nested objects within a document. Suppose I have a mongoose Schema as follows:

```
var posts = mongoose.Schema({
    title : String,
    post : String,
    comments : [{
        status : Number,
        title : String,
        comment : String
    }]
});
```

I want to search for all comments in a particular post, where the status of the comment equals 1. This is what I have tried, but it doesn't work:

```
Post.find(
    {_id: req.params.id, comments: { status: 1 }},
    null,
    {},
    function (err, data) {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        return res.json(data);
    }
);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Use "dot notation":

```
Post.find(
    {
        _id: req.params.id, 
        "commments": { "$exists": true }, 
        "comments.status": 1 
    },
    function (err, data) {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        return res.json(data);
    }
);
```

Without that you are asking for comments to be "exactly" in the form you are querying and **only** contain "status" as a field.

If all you want to return are just the matching comments of an array you basically have two options.Either you use the [positional `$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) operator in order to return only the **first** matching element of an array, which is it's current restriction. Or you use the aggregation framework in order to return all of the items:

```
Post.aggregate(
    [
        // Initial match is on only the documents that contain
        { "$match": {
            "_id": req.params.id,
            "comments": { "$exists": true },
            "comments.status": 1
        }},

        // Unwind the array to "de-normalize" as documents
        { "$unwind": "$comments" },

        // Match the "unwound" documents
        { "$match": { 
            "comments.status": 1
        }},

        // Push back as an array
        { "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "title": { "$first": "$title },
            "post": { "$first": "$post" },
            "comments": { "$push": "$comments" }
        }}
    ],
    function(err,data) {

        // work in here
})
```

Or with MongoDB 2.6 and upwards you can do that "in-place" using [**`$map`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) instead:

```
Post.aggregate(
    [
        // Initial match is on only the documents that contain
        { "$match": {
            "_id": req.params.id,
            "comments": { "$exists": true },
            "comments.status": 1
        }},

        // Project matching items only
        { "$project": {
           "title": 1,
           "post": 1,
           "comments": {
               "$setDifference": [
                   { 
                       "$map": {
                           "input": "$comments",
                           "as": "el",
                           "in": {
                               "$cond": [
                                   { "$eq": [ "$$el.status", 1 ] },
                                   "$$el",
                                   false
                               ]
                           }
                       }
                   },
                   [false]
               ]
           }
        }}
    ],
    function(err,data) {

        // work in here
})
```

So the difference here is matching the "document" that contains the conditions you specify in the query and "filtering" the array members that **only** match the specification of your query.

Comment: I tried that, but it's still returning all comments, not just those with status = 1.

Comment: @ChrisPaterson The query form with find only matches "documents" which contain the whole array. Applying a "filter" to the array contents of the document is a different thing. See the additional information.

Comment: I'm unable to get any of the above to work. I get this message in the console: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'comments' of undefined". Also, I'm using mongo 2.4.

Comment: @ChrisPaterson That means you have documents that do not contain a comments field. I have altered the examples to include the `$exists` operator in the query that requires this field in the document otherwise it will not attempt to match